# Minimize the lyapunov control function to receive the best control law

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, control-theory, optimal-control, lyapunov-functions

Assume that we have a nonlinear mass spring damper system.
[image]

$$m\ddot{x} + b\dot{x} |\dot{x}| + k_0 x + k_1 x^3 = u$$

And we find the lyapunov function of it. This function sums all the kinetic energy and potential energy.

$$
V(\dot x, x) = \frac{1}{2}\dot x^2+\frac{1}{2}k_0 x^2+\frac{1}{4}k_1x^4
$$

Remember that the state variables are time independent i.e $x(t) = x$

$$
\dot V(\dot x, x) =  m \dot x\ddot x + k_0 x\dot x + k_1x^3\dot x
$$

We find $\ddot x$ form the first equation(eliminating):

$$
\ddot x = \frac{u}{m} - \frac{b \dot x\vert\dot x\vert}{m} - \frac{k_0 x}{m} - \frac{k_1 x^3}{m}
$$

And the lyapunov function will be:

$$
\dot V(\dot x, x) = m \dot x (\frac{u}{m} - \frac{b \dot x\vert\dot x\vert}{m} - \frac{k_0 x}{m} - \frac{k_1 x^3}{m}) +k_0 x\dot x + k_1x^3\dot x = \dot x u - b\dot x^2\vert\dot x\vert
$$

Result:

$$\dot V(\dot x, x) = \dot x u - b\dot x^2\vert\dot x\vert$$

Now we assume a control law gains $L_1, L_2$ where $r$ is the reference vector.

$$u = -L_1\dot x - L_2 x + r$$

We will then get the function:

$$\dot V(\dot x, x) = \dot x (-L_1\dot x - L_2 x + r) - b\dot x^2\vert\dot x\vert = -  L_1\dot x^2  - L_2 x \dot x+ \dot x  r - b\dot x^2\vert\dot x\vert$$

This is the objective function, which I want to minimize.

$$J(L_1, L_2) = \int_{i}^N (-  L_1\dot x^2  - L_2 x \dot x+ \dot x  r - b\dot x^2\vert\dot x\vert)$$

**Question:**

How can find the gains $L_1, L_2$ by minimizing $J$?
Do I first need to do a simulation for the open loop system, then collect $\dot x$ and $x$ states? What if the system is unstable i.e inverted pendulum. Then a open loop simulation won't help me to collecting $\dot x$ and $x$ states.

Comment: If your control law is stable, then $\dot{V}$ should be negative semidefinite, so minimizing its summation (I assume it actually should be an integral?) would be impossible, since otherwise the minimizing solution would be when the state blows up to infinity, but then the system would unstable. So you probably want to maximize the integral of $\dot{V}$ or equivalently minimizing the integral of $-\dot{V}$.

Comment: Yes! It will be an integral instead of summation. My goal is to develop a lyapunov controller which computes the best control law with taking account of system limits, i.e constraints. Why would I maximize the integral of $\dot V$? Shouldn't that be as low as possible?

Comment: Or is this lyapunov method only a trail and error method? Step 1: Assume a arbitrary control law. Step 2: Do the state feedback simulation. Step 3: Collect all the trajectories and put in the lyapunov function. Step 4: See of the lyapunov function did decrease or increase.

Comment: But as low as possible for a (semi) negative definite function is minus infinity, which would correspond with either $x$ or $\dot{x}$ going to infinity as well.

Comment: So, what should I do? Use the lyapunov function to check how "good" the system did the feedback of trajectories? Trail and error in other words.

Comment: From what I am aware of Lyapunov function are not usually used for optimal control problems. A more common way is to shape your $\dot{V}$ such that it is (semi) negative definite such that your system is asymptotically or exponentially stable. Your system is exponentially stable when $\dot{V}\leq-\alpha V$ for positive $\alpha$. Namely in that case $\|V(t)\|\leq e^{-\alpha\,t}\|V(0)\|$.

Comment: I thought that I could use laypunov to find the best optimal control law. Or it probably is not a control law I seeking? Ever heard about lyapunov redesign?

Comment: Okej! I understand now. I need to find the lyapunov control function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Lyapunov_function Seems to be a very good and nonlinear controller.

Comment: control consists of stability and performance. The first (stability) is essential and the second depends on physical limitations and depends on ad hoc needs. It is good practice to consider those two things separately and then try to unify as possible the design.

Comment: You might want to take a look at what is called "Sontag's formula" [see here for example](https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/mcgood/436-459/backstepping/Backstepping2-Basic_backstepping.pdf) but of course you need to first find a Control Lyapunov Function.

Comment: @ITA So backstepping is just an extension for CLF?

Comment: @ITA Is that backstepping technique good or bad? What's the pros and cons? Very important for me.

Comment: Backstepping is one method which utilizes CLF's to formally guarantee stabilizing controls for certain classes of systems. As with any theoretical technique, when actually implementing into a system; one has to watch out for numerical stability, etc. I am not familiar with these ... maybe someone who can provide an answer will also provide insight into topics in the comments.

Comment: @ITA Isn't Backstepping a cascade controlled CLF?